# Excel: Get Top 3 Values and Names

Tags: excel, sorting, rank

I am trying to get the top 3 distinct Scores(result of a formula) as well as the names of the analysts who got those (3 highest)scores. I've tried using RANK, SORT, LARGE and all give me weird results.

This is the result I am going for. Note that the number of analysts per score varies.

[image: desiredresult]

Here's what I get using RANK.

[image: rank]

Here's what I get using SORT.

[image: sort]

Here's what I get using LARGE

[image: large]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Maybe I'm using the wrong function so I'd appreciate a lot if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: ive tried all your suggested formulas and they all worked. thank you so much! Im wondering how i could get a list of names that got the 3 highest scores. i didnt ask it in my post because i thought it would be easy to do it using VLOOKUP then i realized VLOOKUP only returns the first result.

Comment: i have just updated my post. If anyone could please help me again. thanks in advance

Comment: See edit of my post.

Comment: See edit of my post.

Answer (score 6):

Option with `AGGREGATE` function:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,($B$2:$B$11)*(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$B$2:$B$11)=0),1)
```

[image]

Additionally, to get names:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/($D2=$B$2:$B$11))*ROW($B$2:$B$11)-1,COLUMN()-COLUMN($D$2))),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `MAX`. The second and third are array formulas.

[image]

Get the largest value:

```
=MAX(C2:C11)
```

Get the largest value that is smaller than the value above (E2 is the cell above):

```
{=MAX(IF($C$2:$C$11<E2,$C$2:$C$11))}
```

Get the largest value that is smaller than the value above (E3 is the cell above):

```
{=MAX(IF($C$2:$C$11<E3,$C$2:$C$11))}
```

Answer (score 3):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula:

```
=LARGE(UNIQUE(B1:B10),SEQUENCE(3))
```

[image]

To get the names, use TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($B$1:$B$10=C1,$A$1:$A$10,""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With a modern version of Excel with Dynamic arrays, you can use:

For the Scores:

```
D2: =LARGE(UNIQUE(Score),{1,2,3})
```

For the Analysts:

```
D3: =INDEX(Analyst,-1+AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Score=D$2)*ROW(Score),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF(Score,D$2),1))))
```

[image]